# Google Play app won't open on Cyanogenmod

Tags: cyanogenmod

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S5 and I have just installed a Cyanogenmod 13 Nightly. I have TWRP and I have already installed the gaaps package. I have google play installed but it won't open when I press it, it would just pop back to the home screen. And I couldn't install any apps online right now because I am the default browser doesn't allow me to download anything. So when I tried download an apk, or anything, the browser simply closes and says "Unfortunately, Browser has stopped."
Please help!

Comment: Change the nightly or wait for another build. In the meantime, report the developers about the issue. Nightlies, by their very nature, are unstable builds, hence, they are not worth the effort for us to find solution for their issues since the next or upcoming build possibly would/should fix the issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question  because the consensus [here](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/recommendation-for-questions-pertaining-to-a-problem-specific-to-a-nightly-build)  implies that a question directly related to nightly build of a ROM becomes obsolete quickly and are not helpful to site in long run.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to download .apk to your computer and then use `adb install your_package.apk` command to install it to your device. [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/) is required to do this.

UPD: Also, as Firelord mentioned in comment - do not use nightly builds. They are unstable. It could be a reason. Try some stable build.